# (Partial) failure installing WiX-generated MSI from elevated command prompt

Tags: wix, windows-installer, uac, failed-installation

As a test case for an issue I'm having with application deployment, I built an MSI following the [WiX Simple Setup tutorial](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/authoring_first_file.htm) and using the latest version of WiX 3.5. My test environment is a virtual machine running 64-bit Window 7 Ultimate.

If I login as an standard user (no administrative privileges), open an elevated command prompt and install the MSI using `msiexec /i testproj.msi`, the directories and files are created, but the test program is not listed in the Programs and Features section of the Control Panel.

The test program installs completely if I run it from an elevated command prompt while logged in as a user with administrative privileges, or if I run it from a non-elevated command prompt. In all cases, the dialog that says "Please wait while Windows configures Test Package" is displayed.

I'm testing this in a virtual machine, reverting to a preinstall snapshot each time to make sure the failed installations aren't interfering.

I've enabled logging (e.g. `msiexec /i testproj.msi /L*v test.log`), and in all cases, the log indicates the program was installed with no errors (return code of 0).

Why does the installation fail to register the program in the Programs and Features list when run from an elevated command prompt while logged in as a standard user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the application from normal user account and then check the Add/Remove program in the administrator account. The entry must be present there. This can occur if you haven't specified ALLUSERS value to 1.

```
<Property Id="ALLUSERS" Value="1" />
```

Comment: Huzzah! Love it when it's something simple.